# ServiceNow Incident table configuration item lookup broken

Tags: url, filter, servicenow

Recently we noticed that for the INCIDENT, PROBLEM, and CHANGE REQUEST tables in ServiceNow, the Configuration Item lookup was broken. If there is already a configuration item selected, when you click search, it will bring up nothing. If there is no configuration item selected, it only brings up one subtable from the cmdb_ci table (router interface table). The weird thing is that for ALERTS, the Configuration Item lookup works.
Here is the Dictionary info from the Incident table, along with the URL, where it doesn't work.
https://devXXXXXX.service-now.com/cmdb_ci_list.do?sysparm_target=incident.cmdb_ci&sysparm_target_value=&sysparm_reference_value=&sysparm_nameofstack=reflist&sysparm_clear_stack=true&sysparm_element=cmdb_ci&sysparm_reference=cmdb_ci&sysparm_view=sys_ref_list&sysparm_form_view=default&sysparm_additional_qual=&sysparm_client_record=session&sysparm_domain_restore=false

[image: Incident Table Dictionary Info]

Here is the same info for the alert table, where it does work:

https://devXXXXXX.service-now.com/cmdb_ci_list.do?sysparm_target=em_alert.cmdb_ci&sysparm_target_value=&sysparm_nameofstack=reflist&sysparm_clear_stack=true&sysparm_element=cmdb_ci&sysparm_reference=cmdb_ci&sysparm_view=sys_ref_list&sysparm_form_view=default&sysparm_additional_qual=&sysparm_domain_restore=false

[image: Alert Table Dictionary Info]

Does anyone have any ideas? Why would the router interface table show up, but not any other CIs, when it is referencing the whole CMDB?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the DICTIONARY OVERRIDES on the TASK table (where Incident, Problem, and Request) are extended from were set to TRUE. I compared them to a different instance, which incidentally did not have as many overrides. The three that were there were set to FALSE. After setting them to FALSE, this issue was resolved.

[image: Dictionary Overrides for Incident Table]